# eGalax Touchscreen not working Jolicloud 1.2

Tags: xorg, touchscreen, xinput, hal

I have an eGalax touchscreen on an Acer Aspire One running Jolicloud 1.2

I have had success getting this touchscreen to work correctly on ubuntu 10.04NBR, 11.04 and Kubuntu 12.04 and Puppy Linux, so I am pretty happy with how it SHOULD be done.

However, I cannot get it to calibrate correctly or remember calibration settings. I have installed the eGalax utility (all available versions) and it does not recognize the screen. Xinput_calibrator works but the config cannot be made permanent. Problems I have identified:

-Joli doesn't have an xorg.conf file and does not use xorg.conf.d for evdev configuration
-Setting configs through Hal doesn't work anymore

The best I can get is a poorly adjusted touchscreen with a reversed Y axis. Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

managed to get this sorted through xinput in the end.

Setting a calibration with xinput set-props  etc etc "Evdev Axis Calibration"  worked a treat.

```
xinput --help for details
```